# A beginner — How do I sort a list when I call a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below, I am trying to sort the list of fruit alphabetically when I call the function **and** only get the first 2 in the list.
I know the final line is the problem, but am not sure how to fix it.
Thanks!

```
def listed(food):
  for x in food:
    print(x)

fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "apricot"]
listed(fruits[0:2].sort())
```

Comment: As an aside: rather than iterating, the list elements can be printed all at once in 3.x like `print(*fruits, sep='\n')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort first, then slice. The `.sort()` method doesn't return a sorted `list`, it operates in place and returns `None`, so it's not useful for a one-liner, but you could use [the `sorted` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (which return a shallow copy of the input iterable as a `list` in sorted order) to do:

```
listed(sorted(fruits)[:2])
```

For larger inputs (with similarly small outputs), you might want to avoid storing the whole result just to slice off two elements; [`heapq.nsmallest` would allow this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
import heapq  # At top of file

...

listed(heapq.nsmallest(2, fruits))
```